# cloning one div twice

Tags: jquery, clone

I'm basically trying to clone a div that already lives on the page, two more times. Here's what I want to clone:

```
<div class="tnt-zombies">
     //code in here
</div>
```

I need to also had a class of enhanced on one cloned div and a class of premium on the second clone. I will also want to add a class of cloned to each of those two clones so when I go to remove them, I can just call the class of cloned.

The end result that I would like to have is this:

```
<div class="tnt-zombies">//other code in here</div>
<div class="tnt-zombies cloned enhanced">//other code in here</div>
<div class="tnt-zombies cloned premium">//other code in here</div>
```

I hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 3):

Try this out:

```
var the_clone = $('.tnt-zombies').clone().addClass('cloned');

var enhanced = the_clone.clone().addClass('enhanced');
var premium = the_clone.clone().addClass('premium');

$('body').append(enhanced, premium);
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/Arzmm/

Answer (score 0):

You could also do this in a single pass:

```
$('.tnt-zombies').clone().addClass('cloned enhanced').insertAfter('.tnt-zombies').end().clone().addClass('cloned premium').insertAfter('.tnt-zombies:last');
```